# Can't resolve "entity_name needs to be installed" on custom entity

Tags: 8, entities

I'm working on creating a custom config entity and I'm pretty confused. I created it via Drupal CLI, configured some fields, adjusted the `schema.yml` file, and everything is working.

I read that I need an update hook with `\Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->installEntityType`. I'm now seeing the mismatched entity definitions error but after I run `drush entity:update` these errors do not go away and it still lists says that my entity type needs to be installed.

```
\Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->installEntityType(new ConfigEntityType([
    'id' => 'my_custom_entity',
    'label' => new TranslatableMarkup('My Custom Entity'),
    'config_prefix' => 'prefix',
    'admin_permission' => 'permission string',
    'label_callback' => 'getLabelFromPlugin',
    'entity_keys' => [
      'id' => 'id',
      'label' => 'label',
      'uuid' => 'uuid'
    ],
    'config_export' => [
      'id',
      'label',
      'uuid',
      'field1',
      'field2',
    ],
  ]));
```

I'm a bit confused since I can already do everything with this entity (create, delete, etc) and export config related to it. Is running `installEntityType()` necessary? If so, what am I doing wrong since it continues to list my entity as needing to be installed?

Comment: You could re-install the module. You need update hooks only if the module is already deployed and you can't re-install because you don't want to delete existing production data.

Comment: @4k4 This is this situation I'm in with this module. It has a pre-existing entity type with quite a few entities already in existence so unfortunately I can't re-install it.

Comment: The support for the drush command was removed from core but still is present in contrib.   See https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates